# How can I detect the IP addresses of other devices on the local network?

Tags: delphi, networking

I already detect local IP address of my computer using this code (use sockets):

```
Function Ip_Local : String;
  Var Acces_Sock : TCustomIpClient;
Begin
  Acces_Sock := TCustomIpClient.Create(Nil);
  Try
    Result := Acces_Sock.LocalHostAddr
  Finally
    Acces_Sock.Free;
  End;
End;
```

What about detecting the internal LAN IP address of the router and, if possible, of any LAN-connected appliance such as a DVR?

Comment: by definition, default gateway address is known already, ask via IpHelper API, other devices must be **discovered**, using UPnP or ICMP.

Answer (score 1):

Using Indy:

```
function CsiGetRemoteIpAddress(const pHostName: string): string;
begin
  TIdStack.IncUsage;
  try
    Result := GStack.ResolveHost(pHostName);
  finally
    TIdStack.DecUsage;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What is the hostname in this case - ?

Comment: I mean ResolveHost(pHostName) resolve ip address of mycomputer if pHostName is mycomputer hostname. I have no idea of router hostname.

Comment: ok - ResolveHost(pHostName) does not resolve ip address for given router hostname, it does for for computer hostname only. At least thus is what i get so far.